# Agora.io web 4.0 sdk

Tags: agora.io

I am working on building a demo of video stream between two (or more people) using the web sdk 4.0.
When the first user publishes, an event is created to listen for subsequent publishers.
This allows the first user to subscribe to the the second user's stream.
However, the second user doesn't see the first user's stream because the `client.on("user-published"` event never fires because the first user is already published and doesn't fire any subsequent events.

Is there an event / method to subscribe to existing users? I tried `client.remoteUsers.forEach(user =>` but I don't know the media type  to pass into the `client.subscribe` function.

How do I subscribe to existing streams?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of user that is user.hasVideo, user.hasAudio.
From there you can set the media type based off of these boolean properties.
There maybe a more elegant way to do this, but this is working for me.

```
 if (user.hasVideo) {
                buildPlayerContainer(user, 'video');
            }
 if (user.hasAudio) {
                buildPlayerContainer(user, 'audio');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code present in https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/AgoraWebSDK-NG/tree/master/Demo/basicVideoCall. This sample app covers the complete code for your query.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the event before joining the channel, that way you'll get event triggers for existing users as well.